# mountain lion install broken?

Tags: ros, homebrew, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the instructions on (http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) to install ros/fuerte on a macbook...(OSX 10.8). I get to the line:

brew install ros/fuerte/swig-wx

which generates the following error:

---

bash-3.2$ brew install ros/fuerte/swig-wx
==> Cloning git://github.com/wg-debs/swig-wx.git
Cloning into '/Library/Caches/Homebrew/swig-wx--git'...
fatal: remote error:
Repository not found.
Error: Failure while executing: git clone --no-checkout --depth 1 --branch upstream/1.3.29 git://github.com/wg-debs/swig-wx.git /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swig-wx--git

---

In the troubleshooting part of the page, it says that the git repository has been removed, and provides some code.

---

require 'formula'

class SwigWx < Formula
url 'git://github.com/ros/swig-wx.git', {:using => :git, :tag => '1.3.29_fuerte'}
homepage 'http://www.swig.org'
version '1.3.29'

def install
ENV.universal_binary
system "./configure --prefix=#{prefix}"
system "make"
system "make install"
end

end

---

Can anybody tell me what am I supposed do with this code? Or maybe this is a red herring?

Thank You!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55069/mountain-lion-install-broken?/) by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok ... still don't know the answer about what to do with the "Troubleshooting Tip", but the workaround is to run the commands in the file separately:

1. git clone --branch 1.3.29_fuerte git://github.com/ros/swig-wx.git /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swig-wx--git
2. cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swig-wx--git/
3. ./configure
4. make
5. make install

But I'd still love to know what that file is supposed to be.

---

Originally posted by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) with karma: 100 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0